# Laravel stuck on email/verify

Tags: laravel, authentication, verification

I just applied the laravel email-verification and wanted to make sure my users are verified, before entering page behind the login.

I added the follwing code:

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
...
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
...
Route::get('management', function () {
    // Only verified users may enter...
})->middleware('verified');
```

If a user registers he gets a note and an email to verify his mail. He clicks the button in the mail, gets verified and everything works perfectly well.

But I discovered another case:
**If the user registers and won't verify his mail, he will always get redirected to email/verify.**
For example if accidentally having entered a wrong email, he can't even visit the register page, because even on mypage.com/register he gets redirected to mypage.com/email/verify!

Is this done on purpose by Laravel? Did I miss something? Do I have to / is it possible to exclude the login/register pages from verification?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you mean you want if the user login but he doesn't verify his email first then he can login but stuck in the email/verify page?

Comment: If the user registers he can not visit any page besides email/verify. Even if he clicks on my landingpage, login or register he gets redirected to email/verify. I only want him to verify after login. He should still be able to register new account or visit the login page ... but I think the standard laravel auth should already work like this (?)

Comment: You can still login with standard laravel auth without verify your email, you can do 2 way to deal with that, using middleware to redirect user who not verified to email/verify or change the code a little bit in login controller (this way you can make sure the user doesn't login yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this issue before, I have this way to resolve that, if you want to customize it you can consider this way.

In `LoginController.php` you can add this a little bit code, I overwriting the default login method:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);
    $user = User::where($this->username(), $request->{$this->username()})->first();

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    if (method_exists($this, 'hasTooManyLoginAttempts') &&
        $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    if ($user->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }
    })

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

You can overwrite and add a new parameter to the sendFailedLoginResponse too to let the method know when to redirect to email/verify page or just add else in `$user->hasVerifiedEmail()` if block to redirect him to email/verify page

**EDIT:**

You can delete `$this->middleware('guest')` in LoginController and RegisterController to make logged in user can go to register and login page, but it will be weird if someone who already logged in can login or register again.

Comment: Thanks already but what did you change? My problem are not failed login attempts - if the user registers he gets redirected to email/verify, and every link he clicks leads there! No way to leave this page then.

Comment: I just add $user->hasVerifiedEmail() to check the user email already verified or not when login, but for your case using middleware I think is enough, but it will make the user in login state because in default the laravel will automatically login the user after register

Comment: Read this to understand using verified middleware and assign that in all your route that need it
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/verification#protecting-routes

Comment: Thanks, I already did - but why is it applied to /register then? I did not assign this middleware to /register, yet it keeps getting blocked :(

Comment: Maybe you place your `Auth::routes()`  inside the route group for verified middleware?

Comment: I only added Auth::routes(['verify' => true]); like in the beginning of the question. No idea why /register and /login is getting blocked - is it supposed to work like that?

Comment: Ahh that's because you're logged in so you can't visit register and login page again, so try delete `$this->guard()->login($user);` in register method in RegisterController so the user who registered not automatically logged in, then you can use my answer above so user can't be logged in when not verified

Comment: You can delete `$this->middleware('guest')` in LoginController and RegisterController too, but it will be weird if someone who already logged in can login or register again

Comment: Ah okay, I did not realise I am logged in as guest after registration. This may be it! I will definitely check this out later - thanks!

Comment: I edit my answer to fit what you think your question will work, so you can accept this answer to let the others know that this answer works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it very user friendly... (I think!)

First: Inside View/Auth/verify.blade.php put a link to the new route that will clear the cookie:

```
<a href="/clear-session" class="button text-center">My mail was wrong, I want to try another one</a>
```

Second: On your routes/web.php file add a route that will clear the session cookie:

```
// Clear session exception
Route::get('/clear-session', function(){
   Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget(strtolower(config('app.name')) . '_session'));
   return redirect('/');
});
```

This will clear the cookie if the user press the button, and redirect to home page.

If this doesn't work, just make sure that the cookie name you are trying to forget is correct. (Use your chrome console to inspect: Application -> cookies)
For example:

```
Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('myapp_session'));
```